# Using of Linq to SQL in Three tier architecture in asp.net 4.5

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

i need to develop a project in three tier Architecture ..but i do not know how to use linq in project and in which layer i should use ..following is my code for three layer
business layer, dataccess layer and presentation layer, business object layer for declaring table variable

business object layer

```
  namespace BusinessObject
  {
   public  class UserBO // Declare Class Public to Access any where
    {
        //Declaring UserInfomation Variables

   private string _Id;
   private string _LogInName;
   private string _FirstName;
   private string _LastName;
   private string _EmailAddress;
   private string _Password;

   public string Id
   {
       get { return _Id; }
       set { _Id = value; }
   }
   // Get and set values
   public string LogInName
   {
       get { return _LogInName; }
       set { _LogInName = value; }
   }
   public string FirstName
   {
       get { return _FirstName; }
       set { _FirstName = value; }
   }
   public string LastName
   {
       get { return _LastName; }
       set { _LastName = value; }
   }
   public string EmailAddress
   {
       get { return _EmailAddress; }
       set { _EmailAddress = value; }

   }
   public string Password
   {
       get { return _Password; }
       set { _Password = value; }
   }
```

dataccess layer

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());
    public int AddUserDetails(UserBO objbo) // passing Bussiness object Here
    {
        try
        {
            /* Because We will put all out values from our (UserProfile.aspx)
              To in Bussiness object and then Pass it to Bussiness logic and then to
              DataAcess
              this way the flow carry on*/
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USERINFORMATION", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", objbo.Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogInName", objbo.LogInName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", objbo.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", objbo.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", objbo.EmailAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", objbo.Password);
            con.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What has LINQ to do with application tiers?

Comment: What has Linq to SQL got to do with this question, your code is using ADO.net

Comment: i want to insert data to databse..through linq query @patrick

Comment: ya @ben but i wan to convert in linq to SQL

Comment: ok i do not time now to read the whole book  @PatrickHofman

Comment: We don't going to do all the work for you. If you have a specific problem, let us know, but don't try to let us do your job by converting that code.

Comment: BTW, read also about C# auto properties. You can't start the house from the roof.

Comment: i read jotabe but how to relate linq to other layer and all

Comment: any layer/tier that talks to the database, given coded properly, is called "Data Access Layer". Linq2Sql can now be replaced by Entity Framework.. start with Entity Framework Database First approach and go from there. **Note: we will not do your work for you, for free**

Comment: I would create 2 projects in the Data Access Layer, one that holds the EDMX and another for Repository. But its personal preference

Comment: thanks ankit   if i add linq to sql class then can we do with it ?

Comment: By LINQ to SQL you probably mean Entity framework ? In new projects with latest framework there is almost no interest to use L2SQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three tier application contains following:

1) Presentation layer -> It deals directly with the users example html pages.

2) Business logic layer -> It is for validation of data and objects prior to sending to database through data logic layer.
Validation can be done at two stages
1) On POST Methods : Basically for those methods which were used to save ,update, or delete the data to database.
2) on GET Methods : Basically used for those methods which were used by entities to display the data at the front end.
example: displaying username or list at front end.

3) Data logic layer : It is used for sending data and receiving data to database.

So, as a summary Presentation layer ->(sends data/objects) -> Business logic layer (validate the data) -> Data logic layer (sends / receive) the data from database.

Using Linq it can be achieved by following resources:

[Linq usage with n-tier application](http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/developing-3-tier-application-in-csharp-using-linq/)

[Linq learning resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29177/Better-LINQ-with-better-example)